# Deploy grails application to Eclipse internal server adapter

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, grails, glassfish-3, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am trying to deploy my grails application to Geronimo/Tomcat 7/Glassfish 3.1. None of the servers allow me to add the grails application. I get the error "There are no resources that can be added or removed to the server" or "Project facet Grails Application version 1.0 is not supported."

The internal server always barfs with permgen/heap error and increasing it by command line does no favour to it. I just need to have an application server running my grails project to which I can hot deploy.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grails tooling in STS has been optimized to support grails apps running on tcServer.  This is working.  We don't have the resources to test the other servers.  Please try running on tcServer (a default instance should have been created for you when you installed STS).

Comment: Thanks for the update. The TcServer is quite flaky for me and usually ends with PermGen errors inaddition to some malformed URL exceptions for the .tld files if I set the servlet version to "3.0"

Comment: How can I test if the app works on other servers if I am not able to add that locally?